Shell Backbuttonbehaviour iconoverride fontimagesource
With reference to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0 I see that the IconOverride takes an ImageSource parameter, hence, a FontImageSource.
However, how is it possible to set this FontImageSource through XAML?
<ContentPage ...>    
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}"
                            IconOverride="back.png" />   
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    ...
</ContentPage>


Do you mean you want to use the type FontImageSource as the source of IconOverride?

Yes, exactly...

You can try to define the FontImageSource in ResourceDictionary and then refer it in like IconOverride="{StaticResource sourceKey}".
<ContentPage.Resources>

      <ResourceDictionary>
            <FontImageSource x:Key="sourceKey" FontFamily="yourfontfamily"  Glyph="yourglyph"></FontImageSource>
       </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IconOverride="{StaticResource sourceKey}">
           
        </BackButtonBehavior>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>



Thank you. Basically it does work, however, now it is shown all the time also in situations where the default would be hidden.

@KasperSommer Do you mean if you set IsVisible = "False" and it still shows?

Not quite. If the stack has no previous pages the default back button is not shown. With the above solution the back button is shown even when the stack has no previous pages.

@KasperSommer I can't reproduce the issue the back button is shown even when the stack has no previous pages. as you said, do you mean when you navigate from root page to the second page and then navigate back, the back button would be shown in the root page. It's better to create Minimal, Reproducible Example and add it to your post, I'll look into it. :)

a simple project with a tabbed shell with two pages. Without your solution there is no back button when going to second tab. With your solution there is a back button on the second tab.

In the second page, the default arrow back button should be overridden by IconOverride="{StaticResource sourceKey}" see this pic as you set in the second page and there's no other back button under this circumstance, would mind sharing a screenshot of the effect you want to achieve?

Sure. Two pages, no icon override. Only click after start is switching to the second tab. No back-icon. link. Add icon override now back icon is present when only selecting second tab. link

I get you, it's related with the structure of your Shell, you need to define your AppShell.xaml like `<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   x:Class="Xaminals.AppShell">



` with no bottom tabs.

Thanks, but why with no bottom tabs? I need the tabs. And your solution makes for exactly the same. The hamburger menu icon is just replaced with the glyph I selected.

@KasperSommer  I think it's because the back button would be meaningless if you can also navigate through the bottom tabs. As you said it is shown all the time.

Hmmm, thanks a lot. I just don't get why the logic is different just because IconOverride is added. It works fine with the default icon...

@KasperSommer No worries, thanks for the response.
